# Terraform - how to remove ability to edit via console?

Tags: terraform

I have looked in the terraform documentation for a solution to this issue but have not found anything. I have a problem where my AWS account has 1000s of EC2s, SQS queues, SNS topics, dynamo tables and tons of other stuff. Some of this stuff is managed by terraform and some of it is not. I want to be able to make it so a given terraform resource is not able to be edited via the console. A simple example of an ideal conguration is as follows:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "my_topic" {
  name = "my_topic_name"
  is_console_configurable = false
}
```

Is something like the above possible to do? Or what is the best way to go about solving this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform itself can't directly control what the AWS console allows or does not allow.

I think in order to get an effect like this you'd need to use very granular IAM policies so that the credentials that your team is using to log in to the AWS Console do not have access to make changes to the objects managed by Terraform. You'd then use different credentials to run Terraform which *do* have the necessary access.

Coordinating policies at such a fine level of detail will be complicated, though. I think the closest approximation of what you showed in your example would be an IAM policy containing "Deny" statements, which you would then associate with all of the principals associated with users who have AWS Console access.

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "my_topic" {
  name = "my_topic_name"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "disable_sns_console" {
  name = "SNS Topic Disable Console"
  # ...

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": aws_sns_topic.my_topic.arn,
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

You'd need to find some suitable IAM user, role, or group object to attach this policy to and ensure that every credential used for console access is associated with whatever object confers this policy.

This sort of "default allow, deny specific objects" policy is tricky because it will "fail open" if you don't set it up correctly. However, if your goal is more to inspire good behavior than to implement an infallible security layer then perhaps this compromise is reasonable.